# Django's LoginView doesn't accept custom AuthenticationForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I have a class `LoginForm` which is a subclass of Django's `AuthenticationForm`. In `urls.py` there is the following line for routing to `auth_views.LoginView`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from my_app.forms import LoginForm

url(r'^login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=LoginForm), name='login'),
```

As you can see, I've been trying to replace the default `AuthenticationForm` with my `LoginForm` by using the `authentication_form` keyword argument mentioned in the Django documentation but the `LoginView` will still display the default `AuthenticationForm`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use correct LoginView attribute name `form_class` instead of `authentication_form`: `LoginView.as_view(form_class=LoginForm)`.

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to add a dollar to the regex `r'^login/$` so that it matches `/login/` but not `/login/somethingelse/`.

Comment: Please show the rest of your url patterns -- perhaps `/login/` is matching a different URL pattern first.

Comment: Oh dear, that was it! Thank you very much. Had `url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` lurking in there before the "overriding" URL pattern. Time to call it a day, I guess...